# Compiling git on Lion gets warnings about SHA1_Init is deprecated; what is the replacement?

Tags: macos

I compiled Git 1.7.7 from source and while doing so, got warnings about SHA1_Init and other related functions being deprecated on MacOS X 10.7 (I'm using 10.7.2 and although I have XCode 4.2, I am compiling with a home-built GCC 4.6.1, but that only changes details in the warning messages).

The header is `/usr/include/openssl/sha.h`; it contains notices such as:

```
int SHA_Init(SHA_CTX *c) DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7_AND_LATER;
```

- Does anyone know where it is documented why SHA1 is deprecated by Apple and what the proposed replacement is?

---

Illustrative messages:

```
$ make read-cache.o
    CC read-cache.o
wread-cache.c: In function ‘verify_hdr’:
read-cache.c:1172:2: warning: ‘SHA1_Init’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/sha.h:121) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
read-cache.c:1173:2: warning: ‘SHA1_Update’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/sha.h:122) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
read-cache.c:1174:2: warning: ‘SHA1_Final’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/sha.h:123) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
read-cache.c: In function ‘ce_write_flush’:
read-cache.c:1403:3: warning: ‘SHA1_Update’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/sha.h:122) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
read-cache.c: In function ‘ce_flush’:
read-cache.c:1448:3: warning: ‘SHA1_Update’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/sha.h:122) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
read-cache.c:1459:2: warning: ‘SHA1_Final’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/sha.h:123) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
read-cache.c: In function ‘write_index’:
read-cache.c:1598:2: warning: ‘SHA1_Init’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/sha.h:121) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
$
```

---

*Grumble: I can't yet create new tags 'sha1', 'openssl' and 'deprecated' which I consider might be appropriate.*